# What are the long term consequences to an investor of these US bank cash outflow?

Tags: united-states, banking, cash, asset-class

I saw two news

[$910 billion in deposit flight from banks in one year](https://dailyhodl.com/2023/05/13/910000000000-exits-us-banking-system-in-just-one-year-as-depositors-take-flight/)

and

[one week 98 billion out from bank](https://www.cnbc.com/2023/03/24/100-billion-pulled-from-banks-but-system-called-sound-and-resilient.html)

My main question is how long term investor protects from any harm that may be building up, other questions are

1. Is this money leaving OUT of USA?
2. Is the money going to different asset class?
3. Is the money going to mattresses or just Evaporate ?

Comment: It’s going to different (bigger, with more government oversight) banks.

Comment: And government bonds.

Comment: @ronjohn if it is going to bigger banks, should not FRED (Federal Reserve Economic Data ) report it, net-out is $910 Billion

Comment: You’d think.  There’s not too many places for (American) money to go when you want the money to be safe: banks and bonds.  Maybe that $910B was foreign money moved to the EU.  I *do* know that lots of money moved from regional banks to big national banks.

Comment: The article says much more than that went into money market funds over the preceding few weeks, which might be part of the answer. It isn't clear whether those count as "bank accounts" even when banks provide access to them... I honestly don't see "harm building up", or money being taken out of circulation, or money leaving the US (seriously, where's a less risky place for it to go?).

Comment: Money market funds are much more efficient when the interest rates on short term bonds are rising. You'll see the numbers reversed once the interest rates trend changes.

Comment: If you want to worry about macroeconomic effects, worry about the apparent determination to drive the debt ceiling off a cliff. (OMG, GOP, WTF?)

Comment: It would help to clarify what you mean here by "long term investor".  Are you a long term investor in specific bank stocks that you are worried will go bankrupt?  Are you a long term investor in a broad US index that you are worried will encounter issues if a number of banks fail?  Are you a long term investor in worldwide equities that is worried about banks failing across countries?  Are you a long term investor with cash in banks that you are worried will be lost if the bank fails?  Something else?

Comment: @justin-cave I am certainly a long term investor. I am not specific to one Bank or one company. Mostly broad ETF of SP500 and tech sector. If banking has problem, it affects other sector also and economy as a whole.

Comment: But "banking", especially retail banking, really doesn't have a major problem right now that it hasn't had for the past decade or two. Specific banks have problems because they took specific risks. The economy as a whole has problems for multiple reasons.  But looking at individual balance sheets won't tell you much about what's happening generally, and how you "protect from harm" depends on your investing strategy, comfort with risk, and how long it will be before you need to sell the investments.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Is this money leaving OUT of USA?
> ```

It is possible that some of the money is doing that. Some foreigners are moving money out of the US, but I would think that the big money was invested in Treasuries.

> ```
> Is the money going to different asset class?
> ```

Yes, especially if you expand the definition of asset class. Some could be going into the stock market, but other funds would be moving from bank account to treasuries. I know I have done this. I made this move in 2022 long before the regional bank problem in the Spring of 2023.

There is another sector that isn't captured in the report you quoted. Credit Unions. Because they are a smaller sector I don't think that a big percentage is moving into credit unions, but with the recent problems with the regional banks some people may be making a shift.

> Is the money going to mattresses or just Evaporate ?

for the average person, they are well under the insurance coverage limits. The problem this year has been a poor choice of investments by some banks, and too much money from companies in excess of the insurance coverage.

If you are under the limits there is little reason to put your money under a mattress. If you are just over the limit, you can open an account with another financial institution.

what is more likely is that people are spending more than they did in 2020 and 2021. This is due to better job situation, more places to spend money, and inflation. Those will cause a decrease in bank balances.

> My main question is how long term investor protects from any harm that
> may be building up

You will have to dig into the financials of the banks you have invested in. Some may have been able to pivot as interest rates changed, others have not.

If you believe that it no longer makes sense to invest in these companies, then you have to decide if it is time to sell.